# Oracle duplicate row N times where N is a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm new to Oracle and I'm trying to do something a little unusual. Given this table and data I need to select each row, and duplicate ones where DupCount is greater than 1.

```
create table TestTable
(
  Name     VARCHAR(10),
  DupCount NUMBER
)

INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Jane', 1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Mark', 2);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Steve', 1);
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Jeff', 3);
```

Desired Results:

```
Name        DupCount
---------   -----------
Jane        1
Mark        2
Mark        2
Steve       1
Jeff        3
Jeff        3
Jeff        3
```

If this isn't possible via a single select statement any help with a stored procedure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  The recursive CTE example @Hogan posted is great, for example, but I believe it requires at least 11.2

Comment: I should have mentioned it's Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d21b/5)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH levels AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT MAX( DupCount ) FROM TestTable )
)
SELECT Name,
       DupCount
FROM   TestTable
       INNER JOIN
       levels
       ON ( lvl <= DupCount )
ORDER BY Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d21b/5/0)**:

```
|  NAME | DUPCOUNT |
|-------|----------|
|  Jane |        1 |
|  Jeff |        3 |
|  Jeff |        3 |
|  Jeff |        3 |
|  Mark |        2 |
|  Mark |        2 |
| Steve |        1 |
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a recursive cte.  It would look like this

```
with cte as (name, dupcount, temp)
(
   select name,
          dupcount,
          dupcount as temp
   from testtable
     union all
   select name, 
          dupcount,
          temp-1 as temp
   from cte 
   where temp > 1
)
select name, 
       dupcount
from cte
order by name
```

Comment: You need to name the CTE columns otherwise you get an error - `WITH cte( name, dupcount, temp ) AS` [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d21b/11)

Comment: This looks great and would have probably worked great, but I forgot to mention we're on 10g. Thanks.

Comment: @MT0 -thanks for the pointer, the name is inferred in SQL Server.